# Data reshape in R

Tags: r

I am new in R. So please help me to figure out the following problem.

My data are as follows.

> ```
> > CheckIn    - ID 
> > 2016/Jan/1 - 100 
> > 2016/Feb/1 - 100
> > 2014/Jan/1 - 100 
> > 2014/Jan/1 - 101 
> > 2015/Feb/1 - 100
> ```

I want to figure out following tables from above data

> ```
>      Jan - Feb - Mar 
> 2014  2  -  0  - 0
> 2015  0  -  1  - 0
> 2016  1  -  1  - 0
> ```

Is it possible in R?

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("Year", "Month") := {dt <- as.Date(CheckIn, "%Y/%b/%d"); list(format(dt, "%Y"), format(dt, "%b"))}]
dcast(df1, Year~Month, value.var="ID", length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the cast function from the reshape package

```
library("reshape")
```

format the data in order to be properly stored in a data table

```
my_data=data.table(CheckIn=c("2016/Jan/1","2016/Feb/1","2014/Jan/1","2014/Jan/1","2015/Feb/1"),ID=c("100","100","100","101","100"))   
my_data[,"Year":=substr(CheckIn,1,4)]
my_data[,"Month":=substr(CheckIn,6,8)]
my_data[,"Frequency":=as.numeric(substring(CheckIn,10))]
```

use cast to get the result you want

```
cast(my_data,Year~Month,value="Frequency")
```